# How do I redownload/restore my local repo to match the Github repo?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, terminal

I am currently doing The Odin Project, and want to reset a folder that is on my local machine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP1jG.png)

The file is located in MAIN/TOP/repo/css-exercises/flex

I am familiar with cloning and pushing gits, but haven't had to do this particular process before.

Thanks in advance.

I am quite scared to do anything, as I do not want to overwrite the other work I have locally.